# game coding in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, keydown

How to make a object animate using keyboard arrow keys . but it will not go out of screen & it is necessary its work on fixed width.

I have seen some game which having a fixed width like 500px . I need to create it in 100% width.

the object has to animate left to right, top to bottom etc. on key press.

i got the code for left side thanks to Adeneo

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
        var left = parseInt( $('#player').css('left'), 10),
            ani  = left > 50 ? 50 : left;

        if (ani > 0) {
            $('#player').stop().animate({
                left: '-='+ani
            });
        }
```

can anyone explain how to work this for all keys.

Comment: but the thing is that when i will use it for right & top it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You've got a switch statement, so just "copy" the logic but for more cases of a keypress.

[Key codes](http://mikemurko.com/general/jquery-keycode-cheatsheet/)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
        var left = parseInt( $('#player').css('left'), 10),
            ani  = left > 50 ? 50 : left;

        if (ani > 0) {
            $('#player').stop().animate({
                left: '-='+ani
            });
        } 
    break;
    case 38: /* Up key */
           ...
    break;
         ...
```

And so on...

Comment: i have already tried this  but it will not work if i go right & bottom and also it stuck on top left corner . Once its reaches top left corner of the screen it doesn't move any where.

Comment: This is how to add more keys. Your logic for those keys maybe wrong?

Comment: i have used the same method as mention above check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/atalshrivastava/ewnq9/1/

Comment: When you get to the top of the screen, your player sticks because your `bottom` variable is 0... as it's grabbing what `top`'s value is, which is 0... so you may want to modify your ternary operator to compensate for when bottom is 0 as well.